# how to host a WCF service on IIS (without Visual studio)?

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, wcf-rest

I have created my first WCF rest service using visual studio 2013.  It works perfectly when I run it from visual studio.

But now I need to deploy it to iis on a server.  I cannot use visual studio to push it to the IIS server as it is on a diff domain (security concerns).

So I have published the service into a usb stick.

Created a new Site in IIS called it 'HostedcGService'
[image]

I copied the files into the physical path folder.
But when i try to access the service using the following URL

http://localhost:4567/HostedWcfService/data/10[image]

My code is as follows,
The App.config file is as follows,

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="svcBehavior">        
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>         
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfJsonRestService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="svcBehavior">
        <endpoint name="" binding="webHttpBinding" address="" contract="WcfJsonRestService.IService1" />        
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The IService1.cs

```
namespace WcfJsonRestService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Service1.Person GetData(string id);
    }
}
```

The Service1.cs

```
namespace WcfJsonRestService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "data/{id}")]
        public Person GetData(string id)
        {
            // lookup person with the requested id 
            return new Person()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(id),
                Name = "Leo Messi"
            };
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

There is also a web.config file.. do I need that? what's the difference between the appconfig and the webconfig?

Web config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->


  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfJsonRestService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:4567/HostedWcfService"

                  binding="webHttpBinding"

                  contract="WcfJsonRestService.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>


</configuration>
```

Comment: what error are you getting when you try to access the service?

Comment: http 404... - see image above